# What could be stopping android users reaching s3?

Tags: android, http, ssl, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3

We have an android game out, made in unity and running on mono (or whatever polluted version of mono unity uses for android runtime). It will occasionally download a file from our s3 bucket. The http address looks like https://s3.amazonaws.com/XXX/YYY.json, and is the same for all users, all the time.

We also have exception reporting via raygun, and can see that there are a small subset of users who don't seem able to complete the download. The exceptions have two flavours: unknown hosts, and ssl exceptions. Here's two representative errors:

- `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "s3.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname` (Android 4.4.2)
- `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed` (Android 5.0.2)

The code is one line, using unity's built-in WWW class and it's compiled with Unity 4.6.5p2. The game is also making periodic pings to google.com - for at least one of the unknown host errors, those pings are succeeding, so it's not as if the player is completely offline.

Edit: Another thing; to get around undesirable caching I was sometimes seeing, I append ?rnd=XXX to the http address, where XXX is a random number.

Does anyone know why these errors occur? Is it something to do with the user's device, or their network, or unity, or my code? Is the SSL issue separate from the unknown host issue? What can be done to mitigate and reduce the errors?

Comment: "close because off-topic..." Obviously, I disagree. I'm not looking for router or switch advice; I want to know how my _code_ can help address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess ('im no Android specialist), but it is possible the SSL exceptions comme from a certificate silently rejected by Android.

For the host error, since it's a subset of user, it can be powerusers who tampered with DNS settings. Or a too much agressive Adblock app.

Comment: I heard a comment on hanselminutes that some large % of SSL errors are because the device's clock has been tampered with, mainly to clockscum games like candy crush!

Comment: That also sounds like a very likely explaination, but those users may have issues with many others games and websites as well